# Error when using Jsoup in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jsoup

I downloaded the .jar Jsoup file from jsoup.org/download. I then ran eclipse and imported the .jar files into a java project. However, I keep getting an error when I type

import org.jsoup.nodes.*;

I want to use the Document class in that file.

I made sure the syntax was correct and everything, but the error won't go away. Anyone know what the problem could be?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the JAR file to project's build path. Drop the JAR in the project's root folder or some `/lib` folder, rightclick the JAR file and then choose *Build Path > Add to Build Path*.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, using wildcard imports is not the best practice. Rather specify the imports separately, or just let Eclipse autocomplete it by entering Ctrl+Space after typing `Document` in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on project in Eclipse > Properties > Java Build Path > Add Jar > select the jar from your project which you imported before > ok